# TypeError: Result of expression 'localStorage' [null] is not an object

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

I use jquery wizard in my Android application. So far I can see the wizard effect and all my subpage are distinguish by the  tags.
But when my app load by Android simulator this is an error.

04-06 15:06:59.939: E/Web Console(275): TypeError: Result of expression 'localStorage' [null] is not an object. 
at file:///android_asset/jquery/jquery.mobile.wizard.js:123

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../jquery/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../jquery/jquery.mobile.wizard.css" />
<script src="../jquery/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="../jquery/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../jquery/jquery.mobile.wizard.js"></script>
```

This is my page header:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    //$( ".inputdates" ).datepicker();
  $('#autoquoteform').wizard({imagebase:'../image'});
  $('#autoquoteform').bind('keypress', function (event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
      //$.mobile.changePage($("#homepage"));
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

When I click the wizard icon, this error will happened.

So does anyone met the same problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work by doing this:

```
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    try {  
        File filesDir = this.getExternalFilesDir(null);   
        File file = new File(filesDir, "SomeFolder"); 
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();  
        }
        webView.getSettings().setDatabasePath(file.getAbsolutePath());
    } catch (Exception e) {
         throw new RuntimeException("Failed to mkdir dirs, " + e.getMessage(), e);                                    
    }
```